# Problem in moving images in C#

Tags: c#

I asked a question about moving [images with timer in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883953/move-images-with-timer) . Some people said to me to use WPF. But I never worked with WPF before. I looked [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) but don't understand it.
Please help me, I really need this soon.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to have a look at Expression Blend video tutorial. Learning and implementing wpf without out tools like Expression Blend is quite challenging. http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197141.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In short, in WinForms (I assume you use WinWorms when you don't use WPF) to animate some elements on the screen, so the following:

1. Override the forms OnPaint method, and inside there, draw the image(s) on the desired positions.
2. Make a backgroundworker tat support sending progress.
3. In the backgroundworker calculate the new positions, then call ReportProgress.
4. In the report progress event method, redraw the images on their new positions.
5. Remember to set the forms DoubleBuffered property to true so that the redrawing is done smoothly.

Good luck! :)