# How can I move `Image` one place to Another place in particular time intervals

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, image, timer

How can I move `Image` one place to Another place in particular `time intervals` in `C#`?

Comment: Which platform/language is this question about? Images and Timers are available across pretty much all platforms and languages!

Comment: I am new to `C#`. I am trying to develop `game` I want move Image one place to Another place

Comment: I've added C# as a tag to your question, so C# experts will see it and help you out.. :-)

Comment: You must also specify which UI/game framework you are using since it affects the answer. Is this WPF? windows forms? Unity3D? XNA?

Comment: Check this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4884272/1577396) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4833916/1577396). This may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using System.Windows.Forms.Timer class you can achieve what you need.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();


t.Interval = 15000; // specify interval time as you want
t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
t.Start();

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Put logic to change picture box location
}
```

By using stop() method you can stop timer.

```
t.Stop();
```

Check out this link: [Move images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833864/move-images-in-c-sharp/4833916#4833916)